# How do I get rid of Newboy's Talisman?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I made the mistake of taking Newboy's talisman after getting him killed, only to find out that it actually was cursed and lowers my armor by 10%. Brutal! Normally I'd sell it but the game refuses to let me, saying it's a Quest Item. Is there any way for me to dispose of the talisman or lift the curse, or am I forever to bear this burden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find an witch named Anezka in the furthest house in Lobinden, just outside Flotsam. You may show her the amulet and she will be interested in buying it.

Comment: This is the quest "Melitielle's Heart", FYI.

Comment: You also have the option of accepting the quest from Anezka to lift the curse from the amulet. It involved you doing all the side quests in Flotsam (not sure if that changes in patch 1.2) and performing a ritual where you be in a rather tough fight. The reward is that the amulet will give +1 Vitality regeneration

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend not "getting rid of it."  When you find Anezka in her house just outside Flotsam, if you refuse to sell it and continue asking her about why she wants it so badly, she will eventually tell you that the amulet's curse can be lifted.  She'll require you to get several rare/expensive items for her and meet her by that big-mouthed shrine head statue in the woods at midnight.  Give her the items, meditate until midnight, then follow her, or wait for her at the shrine.  She'll do some hocus-pocus while a bunch of wraiths try to kill you.  Once you've killed a certain number of them, her ritual will end and she'll return the amulet to you--now imbued with the power of Vitality regeneration.  You don't have to wear or otherwise equip the amulet for it's power to help you.  Just keep it in your inventory.

Btw, killing the wraiths is relatively difficult.  I recommend you keep several grapeshot bombs equipped, make generous use of the Quen and run to the edge of the woods.  At a certain distance, the wraiths will stop following you.  You can then repeatedly step in and out of combat for short bursts of fighting and lob grapeshots at them when they start to run away.  The wraiths will continue to respawn so that there are always three attacking you, until you've defeated a certain number of them.  Then the ritual will end and the remaining ones will disappear.  Don't allow Anezka's ritual to be interrupted at any point.  If she turns away from the shrine with her hands raised, she will eventually go back to doing the ritual, but from what I've read, she will never finish the ceremony and the wraiths will never stop coming.